# Error with timezone when fit prophet model

Tags: r, timezone, prophet

I plan to use prophet for prediction. But when I fit a model I receive error.
I use example from modeltime.resample:

```
library(dplyr)  
library(lubridate)  
library(parsnip)  
library(rsample)  
library(timetk)  
library(modeltime)  

m750 <- m4_monthly %>% filter(id == "M750")

splits <- initial_time_split(m750, prop = 0.8)

model_spec <- prophet_boost(
    learn_rate = 0.1
) %>%
    set_engine("prophet_xgboost")

model_fit <- model_spec %>%
    fit(log(value) ~ date + as.numeric(date) + month(date, label = TRUE),
        data = training(splits))
```

When I fit model I get

> Error: CCTZ: Unrecognized timezone of the input vector: "GMT"

I try reinstall rstan and prophet packages, but error repeat.

My Session Info:

```
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)  
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)  
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 14393)  

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Ukrainian_Ukraine.1251  LC_CTYPE=Ukrainian_Ukraine.1251   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Ukrainian_Ukraine.1251 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Ukrainian_Ukraine.1251    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] modeltime_1.2.2 timetk_2.8.1    rsample_1.0.0   parsnip_1.0.0   lubridate_1.8.0 dplyr_1.0.9
```

Answer (score 1):

I deleted and reinstalled lubridate package. And now it works!

Comment: i have the same problem but deleted lubridate didn't solve it :(