# how can I fix date error when using modeltime's prophet_reg() for machine learning

Tags: r, tidymodels, timetk

I'm trying to use excellent timetk and modeltime package but for some reason on my work computer I get an error (that I don't get with my home computer). It appears related to lubridate but I'm unsure -- can anyone help?

Specifically when fitting the model I get the below error output.

`Error in C_force_tz(to_posixct(time), tz, roll_dst) :  CCTZ: Unrecognized output timezone: "GMT"`

I'm using R `4.3` in `2023.03.1 Build 446` but had the same error when I had R 4.2.3

I tried the solution listed below and it didn't work

[Error with timezone when fit prophet model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73032947/error-with-timezone-when-fit-prophet-model)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(timetk)
library(modeltime)
library(tidymodels)

df <- timetk::bike_sharing_daily
split <- timetk::time_series_split(df,assess = 200,cumulative = TRUE)


(train <- training(split))
(test <- testing(split))


rec <- recipe(cnt~dteday,data=train)

mod <- prophet_reg() %>% 
  set_engine("prophet")

wf <- workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(rec) %>% 
  add_model(mod)


wf %>% fit(data=train)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was caused by dependency of lubridate. I forget which underlying package but re-installing the lubridate dependencies fixed the issue.